# Type 1 and Type 2 Errors

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

A fabric manufacturer believes that the proportion of orders for raw material arriving late is p =0 .6. If a random sample of 10 orders shows that 3 or fewer arrived late, the hypothesis that p =0 .6 should be rejected in favor of the alternative p<0.6. Use the binomial distribution.

(a) Find the probability of committing a type I error if the true proportion is p =0 .6.

What I have tried... 
mean= 6 s.d. = 1.549 z= -1.936
and get probs of .02ish
However the answer is about .05 how do you get that

(b) Find the probability of committing a type II error for the alternatives p =0 .3, p =0 .4, and p =0 .5.

Comment: Your computation of the mean, SD, and a Z-value, along with using the Normal distribution tables to obtain a p-value near 0.02, all indicate you haven't followed the instructions to "use the binomial distribution."

Comment: Can you explain what Im missing. Isnt mean= nq, in this case 10 and .6= 6 and standard devitation is sqaureroot of npq. and then z = xbar- meant/ standard devition, so 3-6/1.549?

Comment: That's using a Normal approximation; it is not using the Binomial distribution at all.  You can find many examples of using the Binomial distribution by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+self-study+p-value).  Some of the hits also answer part (b) of your question, such as the extensively worked-out calculations in the question asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108429 .

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried (eg, re: 2) & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.